# New search URL not populating

Tags: javascript, url, google-chrome-extension, tabs

I am building an extension that allows you to search google news for selected text via contextMenu, but the selected text doesn't show up in my query.  What am I missing?

### background.js

```
//creates a context menu When selection is made
contextMenus.createSelectText = chrome.contextMenus.create(
    {"title":"Search for '%s'",
    "contexts": ["selection"],
    "id": "selectedtext"
    });


var searchURL = 'https://news.google.com/search?q=' + window.getSelection().toString();

function searchGoogleForString(url) {
    chrome.tabs.create({url: searchURL});
}
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(onRequest);
function onRequest(info, tab) {
    console.log("User clicked Context Menu Search for " + "selectedtext");
    searchGoogleForString(tab["url"]);
}
```

### manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Find in Da News",
  "description": "Find a similar article",
  "version": "0.1.1",
  "permissions": [
    "contextMenus",
    "tabs",
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["scripts/background.js"],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "icons": {
    "48": "squatch.png",
    "128": "squatch.png"
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "squatch.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: The background script runs in its own separate hidden background page so getSelection() won't help you as it's empty there. Your listener for onClicked already receives the selected text in `info.selectionText`, see [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus#event-onClicked).

Comment: Thanks. I used messaging between the content.js and background to send and receive responses.  It was working both ways, but the problem now is that It searches for  [object Object] and when I use JSON.stringify(selectedText) it gives me allllll the info about the selected Text rather than the string itself  ```function sendServiceRequest(selection) {
 var searchQuery = encodeURIComponent(selection.toString())
 var serviceCall = 'https://news.google.com/search?q=' + searchQuery;
 chrome.tabs.create({url:serviceCall});```

Comment: My point was you don't need messaging and content scripts at all, just use info.selectionText directly....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work.  Had to use messaging and add JSON.stringify(info.selectionText); Here's what I did in case anyone encounters the same problem:

### background.js

```
var contextMenus = {};
//creates a context menu WHEN selection is made
contextMenus.createSelectText = 
    chrome.contextMenus.create(
        {"title":"Search for '%s'",
        "contexts": ["selection"],

        },
        function (){
        if(chrome.runtime.lastError){
            console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
        }
    }
);


chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(sendServiceRequest);

chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(tab){
    chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {method: "getSelection"}, function(response){
        sendServiceRequest(response.data);
    });
});

function sendServiceRequest(info, selection) {

    var serviceCall = 'https://news.google.com/search?q=' + JSON.stringify(info.selectionText);
    chrome.tabs.create({url:serviceCall});
    console.log(serviceCall);
}
```

### contentscript.js

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse){
    if(request.method == "getSelection")
        else
    sendResponse({});
})
```